# Shutdown doesnt power off

Tags: shutdown

I have recently updated from 20.04 to 21.10. Since the last couple of days I am not able to power off my computer by clicking the power off button. Tried a number of things like updating GRUB including making the following change:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
Still, the problem persists.
I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad S145 AMD A4 laptop.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you provide logs?

Comment: "I am not able to power off my computer by clicking the power off button.": describe what happens instead of powering off.

Comment: @AndréKugland I am really sorry, but I am a novice; can you please tell me how to get the logs?

Comment: @vanadium when I click the power off button from the top right corner, the screen goes blank/ black but the power key remains lighted and the fan of the computer keeps running. It remains like this till the time I manually long-press the power key to power off the machine. Once the machine powers off, I have to press the power key again to power it on. Then I get the log in screen of Ubuntu

Comment: That describes clearly what happens and therefore should be included in your question: use "edit" and add this to your question so everyone sees that: comments may not be read and may disappear.